# shatter or spread out object when explosion take place

Tags: xcode4.2

there is a bomb placed in the frame..5 objects are placed around the bomb. When the bomb explodes, these 5 objects need to be shattered away. The objects must move away from the bomb in a straight line path ( can be diagonally. vertically or horizontally). These objects must be in the frame even after explosion.